# Azure Active Directory, App registrations, reply url with hash

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want the navigate back to an Angular application after logging in through Azure AD. The reply url i want is:

http://localhost:4200/#/authcallback

I tried escaping the #:
http://localhost:4200/%23/authcallback

Is there anyway to make Azure AD to redirect an url with hash?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue. I'm looking into whether there is a workaround. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/100

Comment: I solved it my not using #. But properly still valid issue.

Comment: Yes, would you mind creating an issue for this in User Voice? I think this is a bug https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35581492-enable-the-option-for-adding-in-the-reply-url-fo

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted it.

Comment: Marilee can you post an answer?

Comment: Sure. I just created a work item for the product team as well and hopefully they can confirm whether there is a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the answer this appears to be a known bug: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/100

Thomas has created a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35581492-enable-the-option-for-adding-in-the-reply-url-fo) for this in User Voice and I have created a work item for the product team to confirm whether or not there is a workaround for this. (I will update the thread if the answer changes.)