# Redirect/reply URLs with hash, Azure Active Directory

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory

I want the navigate back to an Angular application after logging in through Azure AD.

The reply URL I want is:    http://localhost:4200/#/authcallback

Is there a way to make Azure AD redirect URL with a hash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Active Directory, App registrations, reply url with hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566795/azure-active-directory-app-registrations-reply-url-with-hash)

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/100

Even though you set the redirect URL with `http://localhost:4200/#/authcallback`, it will return `https://localhost:4200/#access_token=xxxx`.

You could upvote the feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35581492-enable-the-option-for-adding-in-the-reply-url-fo), and there is a workaround in the comment.

> Workaround - an endpoint that remembers the correct application link including the
> hash tag, redirecting itself to that correct link.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work